# glibc configure error: yacc/bison missing

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I'm following the instructions from [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/index.html) but with a twist: I'm only following parts of Section 5 - Constructing a Temporary System to the extent that I can build my own GCC, reason being that this is a work machine, and I don't have root privileges.  It was going all right until I ran into an error configuring `glibc`:

```
configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: as GNU ld make bison compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

After some investigation, it turns out that I'm not satisfying this condition that's required for LFS:

```
/usr/bin/yacc is a symbolic link to bison or a small script that executes bison.
```

Turns out that there is no such file at `/usr/bin/yacc` (although `bison` does exist).  However, because I don't have root privileges at work, I can't create a symbolic link there.  Is there a workaround here?

Comment: Install it somewhere else in your path, use that.

Answer (score 5):

Current glibc versions need the bison program to build (and not yacc).  You can download the bison source and build them like this:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/bison-3.2.tar.gz
tar xf bison-3.2.tar.gz
cd bison-3.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/install
make
make install
```

Then you can put the `$HOME/install/bin` directory on the command search path:

```
PATH=$HOME/install/bin:$PATH
```

At this point, glibc's `configure` script should pick up that bison version.

Older versions of glibc (before 2.27) ship the bison-generated files as part of the sources, so that bison is optional.  Apparently the instructions you are following have not been updated to reflect the new requirement for bison.