# installing anaconda in aarch64 linux

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, glibc, oraclelinux

i am trying to install anaconda for aarch64 linux . the instance is setup in oracle cloud and the image used for the instance is oracle linux 8

i downloaded the distribution for anacoda from the repository

> Anaconda3-2021.04-Linux-aarch64.sh

when i tried to execute it
i am getting the error

```
Unpacking payload ...
[29237] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIuLAg7E/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIuLAg7E/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
[29242] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEI8iOwEM/libpython3.8.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/_MEI8iOwEM/libpython3.8.so.1.0)
```

so when i checked the version i am getting

```
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper
```

so i tried updating it to 2.28
i downloaded the files required from the repository

> glibc-2.28.tar.gz

```
cd glibc-2.28/
mkdir build
cd build/
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.28
```

when i run these commands i am getting the following below

```
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking whether g++ can link programs... no
checking for sysdeps preconfigure fragments... aarch64 alpha arm hppa i386 m68k microblaze mips nios2 powerpc riscv s390 sh sparc x86_64
checking for use of fpu sysdeps directories... yes
checking for -fstack-protector... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-strong... yes
checking for -fstack-protector-all... yes
checking for assembler and linker STT_GNU_IFUNC support... yes
checking for gcc attribute ifunc support... yes
checking if compiler warns about alias for function with incompatible types... no
checking sysdep dirs... sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64 sysdeps/aarch64/nptl sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64 sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux sysdeps/nptl sysdeps/pthread sysdeps/gnu sysdeps/unix/inet sysdeps/unix/sysv sysdeps/unix sysdeps/posix sysdeps/aarch64/fpu sysdeps/aarch64/multiarch sysdeps/aarch64 sysdeps/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-128 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64 sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 sysdeps/ieee754 sysdeps/generic
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether as is GNU as... yes
checking whether ld is GNU ld... yes
checking for as... as
checking version of as... 2.27, ok
checking for ld... ld
checking version of ld... 2.27, ok
checking for gnumake... no
checking for gmake... gmake
checking version of gmake... 3.82, bad
checking for gnumsgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... no
checking for msgfmt... msgfmt
checking version of msgfmt... 0.19.8.1, ok
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking version of makeinfo... 5.1, ok
checking for sed... sed
checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.0.2, ok
checking for bison... no
checking if gcc is sufficient to build libc... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for python3... python3
configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make bison compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

here i tried to install bison accounding to this link
[glibc configure error: yacc/bison missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735137/glibc-configure-error-yacc-bison-missing)

i am getting the following

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking for Minix Amsterdam compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether pragma GCC diagnostic push works... yes
checking whether C++ compiler handles -Werror -Wunknown-warning-option... no
checking whether C++ compiler handles -fno-exceptions... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++98... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++98 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++03... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++03 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++11... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++14... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++17... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++2a... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports POSIXLY_CORRECT=1... yes
checking whether g++ builds executables that work... no
checking whether g++ supports POSIXLY_CORRECT=1... no
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces... configure: error: no acceptable m4 could be found in $PATH.
GNU M4 1.4.6 or later is required; 1.4.16 or newer is recommended.
GNU M4 1.4.15 uses a buggy replacement strstr on some systems.
Glibc 2.9 - 2.12 and GNU M4 1.4.11 - 1.4.15 have another strstr bug.
[root@skadebot bison-3.2]# make
There seems to be no Makefile in this directory.
You must run ./configure before running 'make'.
make: *** [abort-due-to-no-makefile] Error 1
[root@skadebot bison-3.2]# ./configure --prefix=$HOME/install
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) -std=gnu99
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking for Minix Amsterdam compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether pragma GCC diagnostic push works... yes
checking whether C++ compiler handles -Werror -Wunknown-warning-option... no
checking whether C++ compiler handles -fno-exceptions... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++98... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++98 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++03... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++03 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++11... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++14... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++17... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++2a... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++2a -stdlib=libc++... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports POSIXLY_CORRECT=1... yes
checking whether g++ builds executables that work... no
checking whether g++ supports POSIXLY_CORRECT=1... no
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces... configure: error: no acceptable m4 could be found in $PATH.
GNU M4 1.4.6 or later is required; 1.4.16 or newer is recommended.
GNU M4 1.4.15 uses a buggy replacement strstr on some systems.
```

how will i resolve this issue in order to install anaconda ?

Comment: Is your system actually up-to-date with the latest glibc for Oracle Linux 8? Did you try a `yum upgrade`? What does `rpm -q glibc` say? The bison build error is about missing m4. Did you try installing that package?

Comment: RHEL 8 has glibc 2.28, and so should Oracle Linux 8: `$ podman run -it registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8 /bin/rpm glibc -q 
glibc-2.28-164.el8.x86_64`. I think you need to update your cloud instance?

Comment: yummi - i want to install this on a endavour-os - can i do this with the according commands !?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install Anaconda for aarch64 on Oracle Linux 8.5 on an Arm-based free tier shape using Anaconda3-2021.04-Linux-aarch64.sh

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.10.1
```

Are you perhaps running Oracle Linux 7, not 8?

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.28
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
$ cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 8.5
$ uname -r
5.4.17-2102.203.6.el8uek.aarch64
```

Comment: i want to install this on a endavour-os - can i do this with the according commands !?